# Entity framework Code First One-to-One relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, key, constraints

I have two entities which I want to be connected 1:1 relationship. User is principal and UserActivation is dependent, but I have no idea how that works.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual UserActivation UserActivation { get; set; }
}

public class UserActivation
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to remove 'virtual' keyword, have tried to add ForeignKey("UserId") or ForeignKey("User"), I've even tried to make [Key, ForeignKey("User") and none of them helped me. I want to make 1:1 relationship using only dataannotations. Any help is really appreciated. Also my both classes has their own PKs.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: currently I am trying to do something stupid and I got "UserActivation_User_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'UserActivation_User_Source' in relationship 'UserActivation_User'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'."

Comment: AFter you made changes to your model did you add/update the migration.  Or do you have automigrations enabled?

Comment: You probably want to mark all of your properties as virtual so that EF can generate a proxy for your classes.  That's not directly related to this issue though.

Comment: this is what I get while trying to add-migration

Comment: Have you tried `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` on the `public virtual User User` property in `UserActivation`?

Comment: yes I tried, then I had error "Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'AppData.Security.UserActivation' and 'AppData.Security.User'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Foreign keys are not supported for 1:1 try:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual UserActivation UserActivation { get; set; }
}

public class UserActivation
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types ‘Model.PersonPhoto’ and ‘Model.Person’. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Julie Lehrman discusses this in [her Code First book](https://books.google.com/books?id=6MdsfFau7jcC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=This+problem+is+most+easily+solved+by+using+a+ForeignKey+annotation+on+the+dependent+class+to+identify+that+it+contains+the+foreign+key&source=bl&ots=cLFV40FLsM&sig=ACfU3U2j0ttdSnPuyepa013gMLLMNFp1eQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5hqHG_4biAhVLs6wKHWkBCGQQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=This%20problem%20is%20most%20easily%20solved%20by%20using%20a%20ForeignKey%20annotation%20on%20the%20dependent%20class%20to%20identify%20that%20it%20contains%20the%20foreign%20key&f=false):

> "This problem is most easily solved by using a ForeignKey annotation
>   on the dependent class to identify that it contains the foreign key.
>   When configuring one-to-one relationships, Entity Framework requires
>   that the primary key of the dependent also be the foreign key. In our
>   case PersonPhoto is the dependent and its key, PersonPhoto.PersonId,
>   should also be the foreign key. Go ahead and add in the ForeignKey
>   annotation to the PersonPhoto.PersonId property, as shown in Example
>   4-21. Remember to specify the navigation property for the relationship
>   when adding the ForeignKey annotation."

Comment: yea, this worked, it made 1:1, but now I believe both Id's must be the same, isn't this possible to make 1:1, but User would use Id and UserActivation would use UserId property to connect?

Comment: Why do you need separate ID's if it is 1:1?

Comment: Here is a more in depth explanation: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations

Comment: thanks guys for help. anyway, I was told to do so, that was the reason. I'm not the one, who decides what to do :) anyway, we made it without UserId as in answer

Answer (score 1):

This post is quite old so I thought I'd post the EF 6 solution

Try this...

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual UserActivation UserActivation { get; set; }
}

public class UserActivation
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the ` [ForeignKey("User")]` attributre be placed on top of `UserId` ? in the `UserActivaytion` model?

Comment: Aha, Thats pk-to-pk 1:1 relationship.