# EF one to one relationship, the property cannot be configured

Tags: c#, entity-framework

An applicant has a notification, a notification has an applicant.

I am trying to implement this in EF, but I receive the following error:

> "The property 'ApplicantID' cannot be configured as a navigation
>   property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property
>   should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection
>   properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid
>   entity type."

Not sure, what I am doing wrong.

Applicant

```
[Index]
[Key]
public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
public string ApplicantTitle { get; set; }
public string Firstname { get; set; }
public string Lastname { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string Address1 { get; set; }
public string Address2 { get; set; }
public string Address3 { get; set; }
public string Postcode { get; set; }
//fk
public int ApplicantNotificationID { get; set; }
public ApplicantNotification Notification { get; set; }
```

ApplicantNotification

```
        [Index]
        public int ApplicantNotificationID { get; set; }
        public bool FirstNotification { get; set; }
        public bool SecondtNotification { get; set; }
        public bool ThirdNotification { get; set; }
        public bool FinalNotification { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReminderDate { get; set; }
        public int ReminderFrequency { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime FirstNotificationDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime SecondNotificationDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ThirdNotificationDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsArchive { get; set; }
        //FK
        public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

        //navigation property
        public Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error originated from absence of `ForeignKeyAttribute` annotation on the second table definition, even each table has navigation property for other table. Try setting the foreign key attribute on `ApplicantNotification` and mark navigation property on both tables as `virtual` like this:

```
[Table("Applicant")]
public class Applicant
{
    [Index]
    [Key]
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

    // other properties

    public virtual ApplicantNotification Notification { get; set; }
}


[Table("ApplicantNotification")]
public class ApplicantNotification
{
    [Index]
    [Key, ForeignKey("Applicant")]
    public int ApplicantNotificationID { get; set; }

    // other properties

    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
}
```

The purpose of one-to-one relationship is `Applicant` can be saved either with or without `ApplicantNotification` but `ApplicantNotification` requires `Applicant` to be exist when saving it (from [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)).

Similar issue:

[Entity framework Code First One-to-One relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376450/entity-framework-code-first-one-to-one-relationship)

Comment: my first approach did have the fk attribute on the ApplicantID, however that did not work and repeated the same error. this however does the trick, strange