# Entity Framework 6 Column dependend on this Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Hi i have 3 or 4 tables which the 4th is the many to many generated

Employee > Operator > OperatorWarehouse > Warehouse

Here are the models

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int UserId { get;set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; } 
    public Operator Operator { get; set; }
}

public class Operator
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Emlpoyee Emlpoyee { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }
}

 public class Warehouse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }        
    public ICollection<Operator> Operators { get; set; }
}
```

and on model creating i did this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasRequired(u => u.Operator)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.Employee);          
}
```

The employee and operator need to have a one to one relation, however i get an error when trying to update database

> The object 'PK_dbo.Operator' is dependent on column 'Id'.
>   ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Id failed because one or more objects access this column.

Here's an extra note

There is already a previous one to one relation which follows the same way and works correctly

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }  

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .HasRequired(u => u.Employee)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.User);
```

Comment: can you look into stacktrace and find out on which migration operation it failed?

Comment: For one-to-one relationships, the FK should also be the PK. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33376665/4934172

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework Code First One-to-One relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376450/entity-framework-code-first-one-to-one-relationship)

Comment: The thing is i have a user > employee one to one relation and this is working correctly and everything is exactly the same, just change employee to user and operator to employee

Comment: i followed that topic and deleted the Id on the foreignkey table just leaving navigation property and worked correctly.