# Nullable One to One

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, one-to-one

I am using Entity Framework Core, and have am having trouble creating a nullable 1 to 1 relationship.

I have two objects.  Assignment, and Request.

```
public class Assignment{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public int? RequestId {get;set}

     [ForeignKey("RequestId")]
     public Request Request{ get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Request{
     public int Id {get; set;}

     public Assignment Assignment{ get; set; }
}
```

I need to access the Assignment from the Request, as well as the Request from the Assignment when they are not null.

If I remove the relationship from Request to Assignment it will work, but as stated, i need the relationship from both sides.

What must I do to have this relationship work?

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376450/entity-framework-code-first-one-to-one-relationship/33376665) ? `When configuring one-to-one relationships, Entity Framework requires that the primary key of the dependent also be the foreign key.`

Comment: @Tom What meant by this public Assignment{ get; set; } in your Request class?

Comment: I left out the other properties as they are irrelevant here.  It's a scheduling system, assignments can be made with out requests, or they can be linked to requests.

Comment: You should read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns

Comment: might want to read on here https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-one-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Fluent API to configure the one-to-one relationship.
In your case should be:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasOne(v => v.Assigment)
        .WithOne(p => p.Request)
        .HasForeignKey<Request>(p => p.RequestId)
        .IsRequired(false);
}
```

defining your relationships with the Fluent API + the ? in the ForeignKey prop, that you already have. dotnet will create both sides of the relationship as nullable.